# How to get the latest records by id Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am using this query this returns all records associated to `id_order` but i want the latest records for id_order
(Adminer 4.7.5 4.7.7)

```
SELECT *
FROM `order_history`  
WHERE `id_order` IN (5499,5500) ORDER BY id_order_history DESC
```

[image]

THE DESIRED RECORDS WOULD LOOK LIKE

[image]

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Enumerate using ROW_NUMBER() and get only rows where this number = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the most recent record for each order using a correlated query as

```
select *
from `order_history`  o
where `id_order` in (5499,5500) 
and date_add= (
    select max(date_add)
    from order_history 
    where o.id_order = id_order
)
order by id_order_history desc
```

If you want to pick a recent row based on maximum value of `id_order_history`

```
select *
from `order_history`  o
where `id_order_history` in (5499,5500) 
and id_order_history = (
    select max(id_order_history )
    from order_history 
    where o.id_order = id_order
)
order by id_order_history desc
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, this gives me old record for 5499,5500, can we sort or filter it to select the latest record for 5499,5500. along with it ?

Comment: @newphpdev Previously considering `id_order_history` for the latest criteria if you want the record with latest `date_add` see updated asnwer

Comment: Hello, sorry its not working properly, i have checked & its  not giving me latest records

Comment: What do you think about below query ?

Comment: @newphpdev can you edit your question and add sample data in textual format instead of image ? Or you can use online tool http://sqlfiddle.com/ to show your sample data then we can debug your issue easily

Comment: Can you please update your answer to this ? SELECT * from order_history o WHERE id_order IN (5563) and id_order_history = (select max(id_order_history) from order_history where o.id_order = id_order) order by id_order_history desc

Comment: @newphpdev Initially I had posted the same query for which you have  mentioned *this gives me old record for 5499,5500, can we sort or filter it to select the latest record for 5499,5500. along with it ?*